# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{4}\sqrt{9t^2+t^4}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4}\sqrt{9t^2+t^4}dt$.

I know I have to substitute $u=9t^2+t^4$ and $\displaystyle\frac{du}{dt}=18t+4t^3$

But what should I do hereafter?

Comment: You can try to write the integrand as $t\sqrt{9+t^2}$ and then do the substituion $u=9+t^2$.

Answer (score 4):

okay, t is positive through the integral so we can pull it out of the root;
$\int_0^4 \sqrt{9t^2+t^4}dt = \int_0^4 t\sqrt{9+t^2}dt$
In this form it's a simple integral you should know how to solve

Comment: Need to add $$\sqrt{t^2}=+t$$ is valid here as $t\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4}\sqrt{9t^2+t^4}dt = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{4}t\sqrt{9+t^2}dt$$
Let $u = 9+t^2$,  $du = 2tdt$
$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4}t\sqrt{9+t^2}dt = \displaystyle\int_{9}^{25}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}du = \left|\frac{u^{3/2}}{3}\right|^{25}_{9} = \frac{5^3}{3} - 9  = \frac{98}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int{\sqrt{9t^2+t^4}}dt = \int{t\sqrt{9+t^2}}dt$

$u = 9+t^2 \implies du = 2t \cdot dt \implies t \cdot dt = \frac{1}{2}du$

$\frac{1}{2}\int{\sqrt{u}}du = \frac{1}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}+c = \frac{1}{3}(9+t^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}+c$

$\frac{1}{3}((9+16)^{\frac{3}{2}}-9^{\frac{3}{2}})=\frac{98}{3}$

Comment: But what is the argument for $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4}\sqrt{9t^2+t^4}dt = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{4}t\sqrt{9+t^2}dt$

Comment: $\int{\sqrt{9t^2+t^4}}dt=\int{\sqrt{t^2(9+t^2)}}dt=\int{(t^2(9+t^2))^{\frac{1}{2}}}dt=\int{t\sqrt{9+t^2}}dt$

Answer (score 0):

step 1: make the expression to become t(9+t)^0.5
step 2: Do reverse substitution
Final answer is 98/3 for you to check